# Counting sort implementation works only half way

Tags: python, sorting, counting

I tried implementing a CountingSort program in Python, based on the "Introduction to algorithms" by MIT, but it only works after the first few elements and I am not sure why.

```
A = [2, 11, 3, 6, 9, 20, 11, 32, 45, 47, 52, 59]
B = []
for x in range(len(A)):
    B.append(0)

    
C = []
k = max(A)

for i in range(0,k+1):
    C.append(0)


for j in range(0, len(A)):
    C[A[j]] += 1
    

for i in range(1,k):
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]

#print(C)
    
for j in range(len(A)):
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j]
    C[A[j]] -= 1
    
print(B)
```

Printed list: [0, 59, 3, 6, 9, 11, 11, 20, 32, 45, 47, 52]

Comment: @Brian Hmm, the start needs to be at least 1 as we access the index i-1, k is equal to 59 which should mean the loop stops after 58, which should be the last element in C. I don't see the error I fear :(

Comment: Rather, check the range of loop four and the body of loop five. Note that `len(C) == 60` and that `C[A[j]]` becomes `1` at the slot of the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS code is working, you need to keep check the index you are creating and assigning

```
A = [2, 11, 3, 6, 9, 20, 11, 32, 45, 47, 52, 59, 65,2]
B = []
for x in range(len(A)):
    B.append(0)

    
C = []
k = max(A)

for i in range(0,k+1):
    C.append(0)


for j in range(0, len(A)):
    C[A[j]] += 1
    
 
for i in range(1,k+1):
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]

#print(C)

for j in range(len(A)):
    B[C[A[j]]-1] = A[j]
    C[A[j]] -= 1
    
print(B)
```